# How to make fireworks slices in td responsive with bootstraap and on the same line on wider screen

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a design that I have sliced with Fireworks and as a result of the slice I got a table with td and so for the design to be well displayed, i have to add a css that makes a display in block

```
<style type="text/css">td img {display: block;}</style>
```

Problem

In my quest to make this design responsive I have been using bootstrap however when I use a bootstrap row to display images on the same line it does not work

For example when i take a row of the table and want to convert it into a bootstrap row by using the images like this

```
<div class="row" > 

<div class="col-sm-12" > 

<img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c1" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c1.jpg" width="815" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c1" alt="" class="float_left img-responsive"/>

 <img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c7" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c7.jpg" width="249" height="1" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c7" alt="" / class="float_left img-responsive">

 <img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c10.jpg" width="216" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" alt="" class="float_left img-responsive" />

 <img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""  class="float_left img-responsive"/>

 <img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r3_c7" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r3_c7.jpg" width="249" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r3_c7" alt=""   class="float_left img-responsive" />

 <img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="161" alt="" class="float_left img-responsive" />
  </div>

</div>
```

The images do not stay on the same line but they are escalated. So instead of getting a result like this

[image] I rather get something like this

[image]

This is the original code of my slice

```
<tr>
   <td rowspan="2" colspan="6"><img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c1" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c1.jpg" width="815" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c1" alt="" /></td>
   <td colspan="3"><img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c7" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c7.jpg" width="249" height="1" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c7" alt="" /></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c10.jpg" width="216" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" alt="" /></td>
   <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
```

**Question :**
How to make fireworks slices in td responsive with bootstraap and on the same line on wider screen